# Laravel Eloquent case-insensitive query

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I want to gather all the tags' ids whose names are in an array. For that I'm using `whereIn` like so:

```
$tags = Category::whereIn('name', $tag_names)->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

I works perfectly but I doesn't have an option (that I know of) that makes the operator of `whereIn` case-insentive.

`$tag_names` are an array of tag names which have arbitrary casing.

`'name'` is the column that holds the name of the tag in the database and has specific casing that may not match the one in `$tag_names`.

My postgresql schema for the `Category`table is:

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    description TEXT,
    num_posts INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: You could try `whereIn('LCASE(name)',strtolower($tag_names))`

Comment: @vivek_23 Firstly, the second argument should be `array_map('strtolower', $tag_names)`. Secondly, the first argument throws a Postgresql error, even if I try it with `lower` instead of `LCASE`. Thank you anyway for trying to help!

Comment: I apologize, I need some coffee. By the way, I checked this on my machine and it does work fine.

Answer (score 2):

The array in the search makes it a little more difficult.  If you want a non-case-sensitive result, you can just force them both to one case:

```
$tags = Category::whereIn( 'LCASE(name)' ,  strtolower($tag_names) )
```

Alternately, if you want to match without forcing the case, you might try:

```
$query = Category::with('tags');
foreach ($tag_names as $tag) {
     $query->whereHas('tag', function($q) use ($tag) {
         $q->where('name', 'ilike', $tag);
     });
 }
 $query->get();
```

Comment: I would really like an approach like the first one but it doesn't work. Firstly, the second argument should be `array_map('strtolower', $tag_names)`. Secondly, the first argument throws a Postgresql error, even if I try it with `lower` instead of `LCASE`. Thank you anyway for trying to help!

Comment: You have to use a raw expression: `whereIn(DB::raw('lower(name)'),`